# PHP display a readable array

Tags: php, arrays, var-dump

I see manual of php.net and see sortie of examples, when use var_dump and others commands for see examples.

All examples sort with  pre style.

But on my own server I see same examples on only one line

```
var_dump($a);
```

On manual see->

```
array(3) {
[0]=>
int(1)
[1]=>
int(2)
[2]=>
array(3) {
[0]=>
string(1) "a"
[1]=>
string(1) "b"
[2]=>
string(1) "c"
}
}
```

On my server I see:

```
array(3) {[0]=>int(1) [1]=>int(2) [2]=>array(3) {[0]=>string(1) "a" [1]=>string(1) "b" [2]=>string(1) "c"}}
```

I think this is a runtime option, which I can change, but I'm not sure. So how can I get the output in the same format as in the manual?

Comment: Remove `<pre>` and try the same `var_dump`

Comment: That's not PHP, that's the browser you're dumping the output to. If you want the browser to display it nicely, you'll have to wrap appropriate html around the vardump output...

Comment: So where are we with this question ?

Comment: If you have xdebug installed/enabled then the output will be formatted automatically

Comment: Not xdebug on develop computer

Answer (score 5):

You are probably looking for the [`pre`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) tag, which will give you a nice formatted output. Just print it before you use `var_dump();`, e.g.

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($arr);
echo "</pre>";
```

Example input/output:

```
$arr = [1, 2, 3];
```

with `pre` tag:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
}
```

without `pre` tag:

```
array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3) }
```

Comment: Well i use this solution. But I question it's diferent. My poor english not explain question clearly. Aprecite your response.

Comment: @abkrim What else is then your question? If it is a runtime option? The answer would be no.

Comment: @abkrim And your question is why the output is formatted differently than yours?

Comment: Ohh my goog... i see code of web page, and put <pre></pre> tags... I apologize for inconvenients. Not expert on php. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I crated this function for this case.

```
function echo_array($array,$name = '')
{
    $debug = debug_backtrace();
    $file = $debug[0]['file'];
    $line = $debug[0]['line'];
    $array = "<pre>".print_r($array,true)."</pre>";
    ?>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="background-color:white;">
      <tr>
        <td align="left">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>
              <?=$name?> in: <?=$file?>:<?=$line?>
            </legend>
            <?=$array?>
          </fieldset>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <?
}
```

With `print_r()` can you pass the array and the second parameter says that it should be return instead of printed out.

I use the debug information to get where this function was called because sometimes I have to many of them, that it can get confusing.
You can also set a name for it to determine what was echoed ;)